# Doctrine DBAL get Server Information

Tags: doctrine-orm

I did not find anything about this in the manual of the Doctrine DBAL or the Search here.

So basically my question is, is there a way to get the Database Server Information using Doctrine DBAL.

PHP has things like "mysqli_get_server_info()" and "PDO::getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION)", so I was looking if the Doctrine DBAL supports something like this as well.

Comment: Consider looking at the documentation: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.3/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html . All kinds of good stuff in there.

Comment: Thanks, I already looked in there, but cannot find anything that offers information about the Server.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I needed an answer as well.

so:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection()->getServerVersion();
```